# Convert from std::vector to std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am trying to use std::arrays instead of std::vectors in my code. But failed,
This code that use vector works correctly

```
void split_dataset(int fold, vector<vector<int>>& vec_X_dataset, vector<int>& vec_Y_dataset,
vector<vector<int>>& vec_X_train, vector<int>& vec_Y_train,
vector<vector<int>>& vec_X_test, vector<int>& vec_Y_test) {
size_t len = vec_X_dataset.size(); //5430
size_t division = static_cast<size_t>(len / 5); //1086

switch (fold) {
case 1:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (i < division) {
            vec_X_test.push_back(vec_X_dataset[i]);
            vec_Y_test.push_back(vec_Y_dataset[i]);
        }
        else {
            vec_X_train.push_back(vec_X_dataset[i]);
            vec_Y_train.push_back(vec_Y_dataset[i]);
        }
    }
  
    break;
```

But when trying to use std::arrays instead of vectors it gives me wrong results...
This is the code that I have problem with:

```
void split_dataset(int fold, array<array<int, 20>, 5430>& array_X_dataset, array<int, 5430>& array_Y_dataset,
        array<array<int, 20>, 5430>& array_X_train, array<int, 5430>& array_Y_train,
        array<array<int, 20>, 5430>& array_X_test, array<int, 5430>& array_Y_test) {
        size_t len = array_X_dataset.size(); //5430
        size_t division = static_cast<size_t>(len / 5); //1086
      //  cout << "len = " << len << " divisoin = " << division;
        switch (fold) {
        case 1:
            for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                if (i < division) {
                    // vec_X_test.push_back(vec_X_dataset[i]);
                     //vec_Y_test.push_back(vec_Y_dataset[i]);
                    array_X_test[i] = array_X_dataset[i];
                    array_Y_test[i] = array_Y_dataset[i];
                }
                else {
                    //vec_X_train.push_back(vec_X_dataset[i]);
                    //vec_Y_train.push_back(vec_Y_dataset[i]);
                    array_X_train[i] = array_X_dataset[i];
                    array_Y_train[i] = array_Y_dataset[i];
                }
            }
    
            break;
```

this is the main functoin:

```
int main()
    {
     static array<array<int, 20>, 5430> array_X_train {};
            static array<int, 5430> array_Y_train {};
            static array<array<int, 20>, 5430> array_X_test  {};
            static array<int, 5430> array_Y_test  {};
             int fold;
            cout << "plz cin fold" << endl;
            cin >> fold;
            split_dataset(fold, array_X_dataset, array_Y_dataset, array_X_train, array_Y_train, array_X_test, array_Y_test);
            cout << endl << endl << "size of array_X_dataset=" << array_X_dataset.size() << endl;
            cout << "size of array_Y_dataset=" << array_Y_dataset.size() << endl;
            cout << "size of train_x_dataset in fold " << fold << " =" << array_X_train.size() << endl;
            cout << "size of test_x_dataset in fold " << fold << " =" << array_X_test.size() << endl << endl << endl;
```

Comment: please show the code that has the issues instead of the correct code.

Comment: You have several `vector`s, which ones should be converted? Which are their size?

Comment: Please, as well as showing the code with the issues, specify what the "wrong results" are.

Comment: That is much better.  Now, please, what are the wrong results you are seeing?

Comment: Works fine here https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TxvoK4W5q

Comment: Thanks for the update :) Now please add some more details about _what excatly_ went wrong. Do you get any compiler errors?

Comment: Content of array is stored onto stack. Size of three arrays `array<array<int, 20>, 5430>` is `> 1 MB` - more than default stack size on Windows.

Comment: I don't have any compile or warning errors, But the results are not correct, the code should split the dataset into train and test sets, where the train set should have size of 4344 and the test set should have size of 1086. But by using arrays both train and test sets have the same size of the original dataset which is 5430

Comment: @rafix07 the elements of a `std::array` are (transitively) data members of the `std::array` object. "is stored onto stack" isn't correct when the `std::array` is in static, dynamic or thread-local storage

Comment: by using vectors the code correctly split the dataset into train set of size 4344 and test set of size 1086

Comment: You specify the size of an array when you create it.  Unlike vector, it does not grow as you add to it.  You specified the size as 5430 for both.  And, in the 'train' array, you are only inserting the elements towards the end of the array.

Comment: @Basya so what is your suggestion

Comment: just posted.  But the size of the array will not change; you will keep track of the part that has been used.

Comment: It does seem that `vector` is a better match for your scenario; why are you trying to do this with arrays?  Perhaps, if we knew the problem you are trying to solve by using the arrays, we could suggest a different solution...

Comment: My professor asked me to use arrays instead of vectors for further usage of the code

Comment: Just "Arrays" or specifically `std::array`? Maybe your professor just meant dynamically allocated arrays (using `new[]`)? For some reason many professors want their students to use good old dynamic allocation (well, maybe not good, just old).

Comment: @churill has a good point then.  If this is an assignment, please clarify the assignment.  If just 'arrays', you can dynamically allocate the arrays inside of the split function, where you know the sizes you want.  If he specifically means std::array, clarify whether you are permitted to calculate `division` outside of the function and pass it in....or make it a global constant as one solution proposes.

Comment: @Basya , he said I have to use arrays, not specifically std::array, but I choose to use std::array because it works almost like vectors, but unfortunately I faced problem where I exceed the stack memory space

Comment: so don't put them on the stack.  They can be static to the file.

Comment: I see that you declared the arrays as `static`, so they should not be on the stack.  So I am not yet sure where you exceeded the stack memory space.

Comment: Don't be fooled by the name: `std::vector` *is* a dynamic array

Comment: Aside: how similar are the other cases for `fold`?

Answer (score 0):

With arrays, you specify the size when you create it.  It does not grow as you add to it.  You don't actually add to it; you just set the value of specific elements.

When you write: `array_X_test[i] = array_X_dataset[i];` or `array_X_train[i] = array_X_dataset[i]`, you are setting the element at location `i`.  So, for the 'test' arrays, you are putting the values where you expect them (as the `i` you are using here starts from zero), but for the 'train' array, you are not.  You are doing this starting from `division`, so the first element you put in the 'train' array is doing this: `array_X_train[division] = array_X_dataset[division]`

You probably want to keep a separate variable for the number of elements (which is also the next index you would use) separately for each array.  Something like:

```
void split_dataset(int fold, array<array<int, 20>, 5430>& array_X_dataset, array<int, 5430>& array_Y_dataset,
        array<array<int, 20>, 5430>& array_X_train, array<int, 5430>& array_Y_train,
        array<array<int, 20>, 5430>& array_X_test, array<int, 5430>& array_Y_test) {
        size_t len = array_X_dataset.size(); //5430
        size_t division = static_cast<size_t>(len / 5); //1086
      //  cout << "len = " << len << " divisoin = " << division;
        int num_elements_in_test = 0;
        int num_elements_in_train = 0;

        switch (fold) {
        case 1:
            for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                if (i < division) {
                    array_X_test[num_elements_in_test ] = array_X_dataset[i];
                    array_Y_test[num_elements_in_test ] = array_Y_dataset[i];
                    num_elements_in_test++;
                }
                else {
                    array_X_train[num_elements_in_train ] = array_X_dataset[i];
                    array_Y_train[num_elements_in_train ] = array_Y_dataset[i];
                    num_elements_in_train++;
                }
            }
    
            break;
```

Note that the actual size of the arrays will remain as you specified when you created them, but you will have an additional variable with the information you need -- the number of elements actually used.  Also, you will always use the first part of the array, leaving the unused entries at the end, which is easier to work with.

Comment: I just tried your solution which seems logical for me, but still have the same problem

Comment: Let me clarify further.  You can not shrink the arrays to the size you want.  The size is the size with which they are created.  But you will have the data you want (the dataset elements from before `division`) in the first `division` elements of  the test arrays, and you will have the dataset elements from after `division` in the first `len - division` elements of the train arrays, and `num_elements_in_test` and `num_elements_in_train` will have the sizes you want.  If you want to create the arrays with the correct sizes, you must create them initially that way, based on `division`.

Comment: Using `division` to create the array sizes is somewhat complicated in your scenario, as you calculate `division` inside of `split_dataset` and you create the arrays in `main`

Comment: So I changed the size of  static array<array<int, 20>, 4344> array_X_train {};
        static array<int, 4344> array_Y_train {};
        static array<array<int, 20>, 1086> array_X_test  {};
        static array<int, 1086> array_Y_test  {};
in the main and foolow your solutoin and its works correctly

Comment: @wala I'm glad it is working for you.  I suggest though that you calculate those sizes from the main dataset size rather than hardcoding (I would suggest making a const for the 5430 as well...the fewer hardcoded numbers the cleaner, safer, and more maintainable your code is.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean

Comment: see https://www.pluralsight.com/tech-blog/avoiding-magic-numbers/

Comment: as extension to this question, I need to  do the same thing but using plain arrays not std::arrays, my attempt is updated in the question , please check

Comment: To do it with standard arrays, you do the same thing basically; allocate them to the size you need (have the size in a const var, or calculate it based on your parameters, before allocating the array), and use it much as you have done here.  You can either statically declare the array or allocate it on the heap with "new".  In either case, you will have to pass the size of the array as a separate parameter; plain "C" style arrays do not keep a size stored internally (or, if your assignment allows it, you can create a struct with the size and the array)

Comment: You mentioned that you updated the question; I do not see the edit to the question for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

`array<T, 5430>` always has 5430 `T` elements. You are assigning to the first 1086 elements of `array_X_test` and `array_Y_test` and to the last `4344` elements of `array_X_train` and `array_Y_train`.

It sounds like you want smaller test and train arrays.

Rather than have a `switch` over the bounds to use, you can calculate the iterators to the relevant ranges

As an aside, the standard library has algorithms for copying

```
using X = std::array<int, 20>;
using Y = int;

constexpr size_t Dataset = 5430;
constexpr size_t Test = Dataset / 5;
constexpr size_t Train = Dataset - Test;

void split_dataset(int fold, const std::array<X, Dataset>& array_X_dataset, const std::array<Y, Dataset>& array_Y_dataset,
        std::array<X, Train>& array_X_train, std::array<Y, Train>& array_Y_train,
        std::array<X, Test>& array_X_test, std::array<Y, Test>& array_Y_test) {

    auto X_test_first = array_X_dataset.begin() + (Test * (fold - 1));
    auto X_test_last = array_X_dataset.begin() + (Test * fold);
    auto Y_test_first = array_Y_dataset.begin() + (Test * (fold - 1));
    auto Y_test_last = array_Y_dataset.begin() + (Test * fold);

    // for fold 1 copies nothing and returns train.begin
    auto X_train_mid = std::copy(array_X_dataset.begin(), X_test_first, array_X_train.begin());
    auto Y_train_mid = std::copy(array_Y_dataset.begin(), Y_test_first, array_Y_train.begin());

    std::copy(X_test_first, X_test_last, array_X_test.begin());
    std::copy(Y_test_first, Y_test_last, array_Y_test.begin());

    // for fold 5 copies nothing
    std::copy(X_test_last, array_X_dataset.end(), array_X_train.begin());
    std::copy(Y_test_first, array_Y_dataset.end(), array_Y_train.begin());
}
```

Comment: Anyway, my proposed solution is seriously over-complicated and yours is far better. SO I'll scrap mine (well, it doesn't even work, according to OP).

Comment: If this fits the parameters of his assignment (can `division` and the sizes be calculated outside of the split function, as I asked him to clarify?) then this looks like an elegant solution.

Comment: @Basya I will try your solution and back to you

Comment: I think you meant @Caleth